# SwiftUI - Present 3 different Views with different parameter

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I need to present 3 different Views.

```
   AddListView
   ChangeColor
   EditListView
```

They take different paramater. `AddListView`  does not have parameter while `ChangeColor` and  `EditListView` takes **Color** and `NSManagedObject` respectively. However for the sake of simplicity, `EditListView`'s paramter is integer in this example.

I am using `.fullScreenCover(item: <#T##Binding<Identifiable?>#>, content: <#T##(Identifiable) -> View#>)` for presenting them.

```
.fullScreenCover(item: $presentedViewType) { type in
    if type == .AddListView {
        AddListView()
    }
    else if type == .EditListView {
        if let index = selectedIndex {
            EditListView(index: index)
        }
    }
    
    else if type == .ChangeColor {
        if let color = selectedColor {
            ColorView(color: color)
        }
    }
}
```

`selectedIndex` and `selectedColor` is `nil` even though I initialize them before initializing `presentedViewType`. And hence, an `EmptyView` is presented.

#### This is the project.

```
enum PresentedViewType: Identifiable {
    case AddListView
    case ChangeColor
    case EditListView
    
    var id: Int {
        return hashValue
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var presentedViewType: PresentedViewType?
    
    @State var selectedColor: Color?
    
    @State var selectedIndex: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                
                Section {
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("All")) {
                        Text("All")
                    }
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button(action: {
                            selectedColor = .blue
                            presentedViewType = .ChangeColor
                        }) {
                            Label("Change Color", systemImage: "paintbrush.pointed.fill")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                ForEach(0..<10) { index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Row Details \(index)")) {
                        Text("Row \(index)")
                    }
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button(action: {
                            selectedIndex = index
                            presentedViewType = .EditListView
                        }) {
                            Label("Edit", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        presentedViewType = .AddListView
                    }) {
                        Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            .fullScreenCover(item: $presentedViewType) { type in
                if type == .AddListView {
                    AddListView()
                }
                else if type == .EditListView {
                    if let index = selectedIndex {
                        EditListView(index: index)
                    }
                }
                
                else if type == .ChangeColor {
                    if let color = selectedColor {
                        ColorView(color: color)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



struct ColorView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State var color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Color View")
                .background(color)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button(action: {
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}



struct  AddListView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TextField("", text: $text)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button(action: {
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}



struct  EditListView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State var index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Row \(index)")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button(action: {
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I have to mention that they do not have fixed value. They have different value depending on which row you need to edit.

How to pass `selectedIndex` and `selectedColor` to `EditListView` and `ColorView` respectively?

#### Update

`EditListView` takes only `selectedIndex` while `ColorView` takes only `selectedColor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have `@Binding` properties inside `EditListView` and `ColorView`

```swift
struct EditListView: View {

    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int?

    // rest of view implementation
}

struct ColorView: View {

    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int?

    // rest of view implementation
}
```

and then pass the binding in the initialisers

```
.fullScreenCover(item: $presentedViewType) { type in
    if type == .AddListView {
        AddListView()
    } else if type == .EditListView {
        EditListView(index: $selectedIndex)
    } else if type == .ChangeColor {
        ColorView(color: $selectedColor)
    }
}
```